# Change theme with a link

Tags: drupal-7, themes

Maybe someone could tell me is it possible in Drupal 7 to change theme with a single link (URL should show into which theme site appearance should be changed)?

At the worst scenario, is it possible to switch between two active themes using only links?

Comment: Have you looked at http://drupal.org/project/switchtheme?

Comment: Yes, but this plugin only allow to swith between themes using select form, and the problem is, I don't know how to change this into simple links. Maybe you could tell me how to do this? :) Would be soo thankfull. :)

Comment: That project already does that. From the README: "When Switchtheme module is enabled, users are able to switch to a different theme any time they follow a link that includes a query string like in this http://www.example.com/foo/bar?theme=exampletheme"

Comment: You can't even imagine how thankfull I am for you! :)
I was reading decumentation but probably skiped that part. Damn!
BIG THANKS for you one more time! :)

Comment: Demn, there is problem anyway. Firefox and IE after changing theme first show page properly, but in another pages theme gets back to previous one. Looks like cache problem. Any sygests. In chrome everything is ok.

Comment: Solved that, problem was with permitions. :)